# Mule Standalone Group issue

Tags: mule, runtime, mulesoft

When I try to deploy a sample application 1 which  runs on port 1001 using a Global Configurations properties file, the application deploys to both the servers.

I can test the application on 1001 port and 8086 port.

Subsequently, when I try to deploy Application 2 on 1002 port. I can see that the application gets partially deployed to Server 1 and can be tested successfully on port 1002.

Can anyone explain this behavior of the Mule Standalone instances.

I am a newbie and trying out different concepts on Mule 4

Server 1 Port: Default port

Server 2 Port: 8086

Group: QAGroup

POC with proprties file port 1001: 8086/1001- Running on Both nodes

Typeof: 8081  - Only running on Node 1

Logger: 8082  - Only Running on Node 1

Logger with proprties file port 1002: 1002- Only running on Node 1

Comment: What is the error deploying to the second node?

Answer (score 0):

Only one app can listen to one particular port. It looks that your servers have apps what ara already listening to this port. You, maybe, had tried somthing and then forgot about it. It is not actual flow or http listener. It is http listeneer configuartion in any flow of any project.

First of all I would check all log files for errors.
Or I would got to both serveres to the folder apps inside runtime folder and search for port numbers. For sure you will fimd duplicates.

To allow multiple apps listen to the same port like 80 or 443 you need Domain project with this http listenet as shared resource.